# How to import an image in an Angular service?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Map of images in an Angular service that are then used to render images in a template using `*ngFor`. The user also can upload any image via a file input which populates this property.

```js
export class MyService {
  private cachedImages = new Map<string, HTMLImageElement>();

  // ...
}
```

What I want to do is fill this property with some default images. I do not want to add any default image handling into the template because I want these images to have the same handling as any other user uploaded image.

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to essentially just import all images I want and set in this property.

```js
import image from 'src/assets/image.png'; // TS shows an error, compilation fails

// ...

export class MyService {
  private cachedImages = new Map<string, HTMLImageElement>();

  constructor() {
    this.cachedImages.set("myImage", image);
  }
  // ...
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Just save the map as `Map<string, string>` (name → URL) and use `<image [src]="cachedImages.get(name)">` in the template. Note that `/assets/image.png` is a valid URL here.

Comment: I don't want to do that as I said in the post. I want the images to always have the same behavior as any other uploaded image

Comment: You'll need to explain what you mean by uploaded image then.

Comment: `The user also can upload any image via a file input which populates this property` - What am I missing here?

Comment: If you want to use your module loader to import images like you do in `import image from 'src/assets/image.png';` create a `.d.ts` file in your source directory (for example `src/ambient.d.ts`) containing the following code `declare module '*.png' { const png: unknown; export default png; }`. In other words, we have to tell typescript that urls ending in `.png` are valid module specifiers which our loader handles.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that simple. `Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assets/default/sl.png' in '/src/app/components/image-upload'`

Comment: @RolandJegorov The how is missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTMLImageElement` represents an `<img>` element in the HTML.

What about creating such element programmatically?

```
const image = new HTMLImageElement();
image.src = "";
```

*Note: this is just pseudo code*

Comment: Thanks. `new Image()` would be correct. This does indeed work. So if I don't find a better way, will accept your answer. :)

Comment: Ended up using your approach. Omitted some details but the pseudo code is this - `export const defaultImages: [string, HTMLImageElement][] = ["src1", "src2"].map((src) => [src, new Image()]);` and then just `new Map<string, HTMLImageElement>(defaultImages);`